# mathematical-optimization tutorials

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

Can someone help me with some tutorials on how I can learn to formulate optimization problems in R?

I am mainly looking for 2d optimization problems. Until now I have found a lot of info on optimization algorithms, however almost nothing on how to implement them with 1 or 2 examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the R task guides are [always a good place to start](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html).

In addition, there was a [recent article](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDEQFjAB&url=http://www.jstatsoft.org/v43/i09/paper&ei=oEDnTre5Dof6sgax86S5Bw&usg=AFQjCNEvt5JGN4z35h7mGX9lzKeGNnhy5Q&sig2=hN58_yc93qoWJzPNV07cNQ) on the `optimx` package in R

Also, if you load up some packages listed in the task guide, then you will probably find some useful vignettes (I've learned an awful lot of stats from those vignettes over the years).